# React how to update a status when I receiving a props from a wrapper component - REACT JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning react and also I really want to solve this problem. When I click on Edit on my component Tabela.js, I send an action to App.js and from that App.js I send an Id code to Cadastrar.js. But when I call the function to change de name of the button Registration to Update, it shows me an error message like that:

Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.

What should I do to solve it?

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import Cadastrar from "./components/Cadastrar";
import Tabela from "./components/Tabela";

class App extends Component {

    state = {
        update: '',
        idTamanhoEditar: ''
    }


    editarRegistro = (idRegistroEditarTabela) => {
        this.setState({idTamanhoEditar: idRegistroEditarTabela})
    }

    updateTabela = (atualizarTabela) => {
        this.setState({update: atualizarTabela})
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <Cadastrar atualizarTabela={this.updateTabela} editarFromParent={this.state.idTamanhoEditar}/>
                <Tabela editarRegistro={this.editarRegistro} updateFromParent={this.state.update} />
            </div>
        )
    }

}

export default App;
```

Cadastrar.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Cadastrar.css';
import axios from "axios";

class Cadastrar extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            tamanho: {
                id: '',
                descricao: '',
            },
            error: '',
            sucess: '',
            tipoAcao: 'Cadastrar'
        };

        this.atualizaDados  = this.atualizaDados.bind(this);
        this.cadastrar      = this.cadastrar.bind(this);
        this.editarCadastro = this.editarCadastro.bind(this);

    }

    atualizaDados(e) {
        let tamanho = this.state.tamanho;
        tamanho[e.target.name] = e.target.value;

        this.setState({tamanho: tamanho});

        console.log(e);

    }

    cadastrar(e) {

        const {tamanho} = this.state;
        if(tamanho.descricao !== '') {
            axios.post(`http://localhost/react-project/src/api/register.php`, { descricao: tamanho.descricao })
                .then(res => {
                    if(res.data === 'sucess') {
                        this.setState({tamanho:{id:'', descricao: ''}})
                        //Tabela.atualizarItensTabela();
                        this.setState({sucess: 'Cadastro efetuado com sucesso!', error: ''})
                        this.props.atualizarTabela(true);
                    }
                })
        } else {
            this.setState({error: 'Preencha o campo descrição!', sucess: ''})
        }

        e.preventDefault();
    }

    editarCadastro(idTamanhoEditar) {

        console.log(idTamanhoEditar);

        if(this.state.tamanho.id  !== idTamanhoEditar) {
            this.setState({
                tipoAcao: 'Atualizar',
                tamanho:{id: idTamanhoEditar}
            });
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div id='formulario-de-cadastro' className='container'>
                <div className='page-header'>
                    <h2 className='titulo-cadastrar-tamanho'>Cadastrar Tamanho</h2>
                </div>
                <form onSubmit={this.cadastrar}>
                    <input type='hidden' name='id' value={this.state.tamanho.id} onChange={ this.atualizaDados } /><br/>
                    <div className='form-group'>
                        <label htmlFor='descricao'>Descrição</label>
                        <input type='text' className='form-control' name='descricao' id='descricao' value={this.state.tamanho.descricao} onChange={ this.atualizaDados } /><br/>
                        <button type='submit' className='btn btn-primary'>{this.state.tipoAcao}</button>
                        <button className='btn btn-danger ml-1'>Cancelar</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
                {this.state.error && <p className='alert alert-warning'>{this.state.error}</p>}
                {this.state.sucess && <p className='alert alert-success'>{this.state.sucess}</p>}

                {this.props.editarFromParent && this.editarCadastro(this.props.editarFromParent)}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Cadastrar;
```

Tabela.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

import './Tabela.css';

class Tabela extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            tamanhos: [],
            tamanho: {
                id: '',
                descricao: ''
            },
        }

        this.apagarTamanho = this.apagarTamanho.bind(this);
        this.atualizarItensTabela = this.atualizarItensTabela.bind(this);

    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.atualizarItensTabela();
    }

    atualizarItensTabela() {
        let url = 'http://localhost/react-project/src/api/consult.php';

        fetch(url)
            .then((r) => r.json())
            .then((json) => {
                this.setState({tamanhos: json});
            });
    }

    apagarTamanho(e, idTamanho) {

        e.preventDefault();

        axios.post(`http://localhost/react-project/src/api/delete.php`, { id: idTamanho })
            .then(res => {
                if(res.data === 'sucess') {
                    this.atualizarItensTabela();
                    console.log('registro apagado com sucesso');
                }
            })
    }

    editarTamanho(e, idTamanho) {
        this.props.editarRegistro(idTamanho);

        e.preventDefault();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className='container mt-5'>
                {this.props.updateFromParent && this.atualizarItensTabela()}
                <table id='tabela-tamanhos' className='table table-hover'>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">Código</th>
                            <th scope="col">Descrição</th>
                            <th scope="col">Ações</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {this.state.tamanhos.map(
                            tamanho=>
                                <tr key={tamanho.id} className='row-tamanho'>
                                    <th scope="row">{tamanho.id}</th>
                                    <td>{tamanho.descricao}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <button className='btn btn-primary mr-1' onClick={(e)=>this.editarTamanho(e, tamanho.id)}>Editar</button>
                                        <button className='btn btn-danger' onClick={(e)=>this.apagarTamanho(e, tamanho.id)}>Apagar</button>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                        )}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        );
    }

}

export default Tabela;
```

Answer (score 0):

In `Cadastrar.js` you are calling `setState` during render `{this.props.editarFromParent && this.editarCadastro(this.props.editarFromParent)}`

`editarCadastro` has a call to `setState`

```
editarCadastro(idTamanhoEditar) {
    console.log(idTamanhoEditar);
    if(this.state.tamanho.id  !== idTamanhoEditar) {
        this.setState({
            tipoAcao: 'Atualizar',
            tamanho:{id: idTamanhoEditar}
        });
    }
}
```

You cannot update state during render. If you need to update state from props you should use `getDerivedStateFromProps`

Comment: Thanks it really helps me =)